# need help parallelizing c++ program with OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have this piece of code, that I'm trying to parallelize with OpenMP. It uses a vector of vectors loaded with points (X, Y and Z coordinates) and then it rotates and shift the points and finds the lowest ones in a grid.
the code:

```
        double min_x = *min_element(points[0].begin(), points[0].end());
        double min_y = *min_element(points[1].begin(), points[1].end());
        double min_z = *min_element(points[2].begin(), points[2].end()); 


        // reduction of coordinates
        vector<vector<double>> reduced_points(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            reduced_points[i].resize(points[i].size());
            for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < points[i].size(); j++) {
                reduced_points[i][j] = points[i][j] - (i == 0 ? min_x : i == 1 ? min_y : min_z);
            }
        }

        // conversion of rotation angles to radians

        #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3)
        for (int m = 0; m < num_a; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < num_b; n++) {
                for (int o = 0; o < num_g; o++) {

                    double alpha = (alpha_gon[m] / 200) * numbers::pi;
                    double beta = (beta_gon[n] / 200) * numbers::pi;
                    double gamma = (gamma_gon[o] / 200) * numbers::pi;

                    // define rotation matrices for x, y, and z axes
                    vector<vector<double>> x_rot_matrix = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, cos(alpha), sin(alpha)}, {0, -sin(alpha), cos(alpha)}};
                    vector<vector<double>> y_rot_matrix = {{cos(beta), 0, -sin(beta)}, {0, 1, 0}, {sin(beta), 0, cos(beta)}};
                    vector<vector<double>> z_rot_matrix = {{cos(gamma), sin(gamma), 0}, {-sin(gamma), cos(gamma), 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

                    // apply rotations to points in reduced_points and store in rotated_points
                    vector<vector<double>> rotated_points(3);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        rotated_points[i].resize(reduced_points[i].size());
                        for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < reduced_points[i].size(); j++) {
                            double x = reduced_points[0][j];
                            double y = reduced_points[1][j];
                            double z = reduced_points[2][j];
                            rotated_points[i][j] = x_rot_matrix[i][0] * x + x_rot_matrix[i][1] * y + x_rot_matrix[i][2] * z;
                            rotated_points[i][j] += y_rot_matrix[i][0] * x + y_rot_matrix[i][1] * y + y_rot_matrix[i][2] * z;
                            rotated_points[i][j] += z_rot_matrix[i][0] * x + z_rot_matrix[i][1] * y + z_rot_matrix[i][2] * z;
                        }
                    }

                    // shifting to origin
                    double to_origin_x = *min_element(rotated_points[0].begin(), rotated_points[0].end());
                    double to_origin_y = *min_element(rotated_points[1].begin(), rotated_points[1].end());
                    double to_origin_z = *min_element(rotated_points[2].begin(), rotated_points[2].end());

                    vector<vector<double>> to_origin_points(3);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        to_origin_points[i].resize(rotated_points[i].size());
                        for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < rotated_points[i].size(); j++) {
                            to_origin_points[i][j] = rotated_points[i][j] - (i == 0 ? to_origin_x : i == 1 ? to_origin_y : to_origin_z);
                        }
                    }

                    //adding shift

                    for (int q = 0; q < number_of_shifts; q++) {
                        for (int r = 0; r < number_of_shifts; r++) {

                            vector<vector<double>> shifted_points(3);
                            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                shifted_points[i].resize(to_origin_points[i].size());
                                for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < to_origin_points[i].size(); j++) {
                                    shifted_points[i][j] = to_origin_points[i][j] + (i == 0 ? shift_x * q : i == 1 ? shift_y * r : 0);
                                }
                            }    

                            // find maximum values in each column
                            double max_x = *max_element(shifted_points[0].begin(), shifted_points[0].end());
                            double max_y = *max_element(shifted_points[1].begin(), shifted_points[1].end());

                            //determine raster size
                            int limit_x = ceil(max_x/raster_size);
                            int limit_y = ceil(max_y/raster_size);
                            vector<vector<double>> grid(limit_x, vector<double>(limit_y));

                            // finding ground
                            int grid_x;
                            int grid_y;
                            for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < shifted_points[0].size(); i++) {
                                grid_x = floor(shifted_points[0][i]/raster_size);
                                grid_y = floor(shifted_points[1][i]/raster_size);

                                if (grid[grid_x][grid_y] == 0)
                                {
                                    grid[grid_x][grid_y] = i;
                                } else if (shifted_points[2][i] < shifted_points[2][grid[grid_x][grid_y]]) {
                                    grid[grid_x][grid_y] = i;
                                }
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++) {
                                    int index = grid[i][j];
                                    if (index != 0) {
                                        #pragma omp critical
                                        {
                                        all_lowest_points.insert(index);
                                        count_map[index]++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This solution works, but as I am a beginner I have a feeling there may be a better one. Also if a 'raster_size' is set to a value less then 1, the computation gets suddenly much slower and only a fraction of CPU power is used. I'm looking for any impovements to my code.

Comment: You should really not use `vector<vector<double>>` as they make several allocations and are not contiguous (jagged arrays). Consider using plan C array since you do not even resize them. Allocations tends not to scale so having this in a parallel loop is clearly not great. If you need a matrix type, then there are many efficient libraries (eg. Eigen) for that. Regarding the `omp critical` in the loop, it is certainly better to build a local vector and insert it in the global one only at the end. Finally, it is not always optimal to use `collapse(3)` since compilers can use a slow modulus here.

Comment: For minimal code change you could also use `std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 3>` which should give the same results as a plain C array.

Comment: But the general solution is using a 1D array (or vector if the size is not known at compile time) with lexic indexing `matrix[i * j_len + j]`.

Comment: Without knowing typical sizes for `num_a`, `num_b` and `num_g` it is hard to argue about how to parallelize that nested loop. Please update your question.

Comment: typical sizes for `num_a`, `num_b` and `num_g` are from 1 to 10, same goes for `number_of_shifts`

Comment: Please add the details by editing your question instead of putting them in the comments

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Victor Eijkhout the best solution is to define a custom omp reduction. An alternative is to do a manual reduction, which is a bit less efficient, but probably still much more efficient than your initial code, as the critical is then encountered only one per thread (instead many times in the loops).

First, you have to split the `omp parallel for` and to declare local/private versions of the objects you apply the reduction to.

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        // declare here all_lowest_points_local count_map_local
        // with the same characteristics as the global version

        #pragma omp for collapse(3)
        for (int m = 0; m < num_a; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < num_b; n++) {
                for (int o = 0; o < num_g; o++) {
```

In your `omp critical` region, you update the local versions instead of the global ones. That way, you can remove the `critical` pragma

And just before the end of the parallel section you update the global versions.

```
                } // end of o loop
            } // end of n loop
        } // end of m loop
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            // here you update all_lowest_points and  count_map
            // using all_lowest_points_local and count_map_local
        }
    } // end of omp parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your number of data points to parallelize over is on the low side.
2. You are right to mark the two lines `critical`, unfortunately that is not good for performance. Since you're using C++ you can turn this into a reduction if you define a reduction operator that merges the `lowest_points` and `count` arrays. I would write a class `low_points` and define the `operator+` on that. Then everything will run extremely fast and almost fully parallel.

Comment: sorry, I'm very new to c++, could you please tell me more aboyt what a reduction and reduction operator is and how could I use it?

Comment: Find a tutorial on operator overloading for C++ classes. The basic ideas for using this in OpenMP are here: https://theartofhpc.com/pcse/omp-reduction.html#Overloadedoperators Btw, a reduction has nothing to do with C++: that's an OpenMP keyword.

Comment: @JakubKučera alternatively you could declare local versions to each thread of `lowest_points` and `count_map`: you wouldn't need a critical section to update them. Then, at the end of the parallel loops you would have to merge them into the global `lowest_points` and `count_map`: of course you would still need a critical section at this point but it would be outside of the loops and executed only once at the end each thread. This approach is actually a manual reduction, a bit less efficient than an omp reduction, but simpler to implement in such a case.

Comment: Note that you have the separate the `omp parallel for` pragma into `omp parallel` and `omp for` in order to achieve the manual reduction

Comment: @PierU so if I understand correctly, this manual reduction would still be more efficient then my code? also the `count_map` and `lowest_points` usually hold millions of values and there is a lot of iterations (up to thousands sometimes), wouldn't this be a problem?

Comment: @JakubKučera yes, more efficient because the critical section is encountered only once per thread. The number of elements is not an issue: instead of having a single huge instance of these objects, you will have several smaller instances.

Comment: @PierU would you be so kind and elaborate more on the implementation to my code? I would really like to implement these suggested changes to my code, but as I'm begginer, I really don't know where  or how to begin

Comment: OK, I will do in an answer (although I'm not very skilled in C++)